# GetSafeHtmlFragment is still not working as expected to stop cross site scripting in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, xss

What I want is, I want to stop user from entering invalid code like `hi<script>alert('1')</script>` or other invalid characters what an attacker can insert.

So For that I tried the below code by using

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public JsonResult InitiateWFfttx(string FSAID, string CREATEDBY, string MZONECODE, string MZONENAME, double COMLEG, double UGLEG, double ARLEG, double MDULEG, int STATUSID, string HOTOOFFERDATE, string REMARK, double HOTOOFFERLEG, int UMSGROUPIDBY, string UMSGROUPNAMEBY, int UMSGROUPIDTO, string UMSGROUPNAMETO, string SPANTYPE)
{
    string strMessage = "";
    string Message = "";
    string msg = "";
    try
    {                
        string strRemarks = "";

        strRemarks = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(Convert.ToString(REMARK));   // here it is by passing the invalid character             

        if (strRemarks != "")
        {
            CTManagement ObjCTMang = new CTManagement();
            ApplicationLog.Trace("Info", "Initated the process", UMSGROUPNAMEBY, CREATEDBY);
            Message = ObjCTMang.InitiateWorkflow_Fttx(FSAID, CREATEDBY, MZONECODE, MZONENAME, COMLEG, UGLEG, ARLEG, MDULEG, STATUSID, HOTOOFFERDATE, REMARK, HOTOOFFERLEG, UMSGROUPIDBY, UMSGROUPNAMEBY, UMSGROUPIDTO, UMSGROUPNAMETO, SPANTYPE);
            string state = Message.Split('|')[0];
            string req_id = Message.Split('|')[1];
            if (state == "SUCCESS")
            {
                //Code commented for optimizing the Job createing response by Jyotir
                //SendEmail(CREATEDBY, UMSGROUPIDTO, UMSGROUPNAMETO, UMSGROUPNAMEBY, "NEW", req_id, SPANTYPE, R4GState, MZONECODE, REMARK, SPANTYPE == "INTERCITY" ? SPANID : LINKID);
                ApplicationLog.Trace("Info", "Sucessfully generated Request Id: " + req_id, UMSGROUPNAMEBY, CREATEDBY);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Message = "ERROR|Invalid text not allowed in Remarks";
        }

        strMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        if (Message.Length > 0)
        {
            msg = Message.Split('|')[1];
        }
        else
        {
            msg = ex.Message;
        }

        //ErrorLog.HandleErrorLog(CREATEDBY, SPANID, "InitiateWF", msg);
        /*
         * Error(string LogType, string functionname, string msg)
         */
        ApplicationLog.Error("Error", "InitiateWFfttx", msg);
    }
    return Json(strMessage);
}
```

Please suggest how to encode this.

`strRemarks = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(Convert.ToString(REMARK));` here its bypassing the html fragment.

Comment: Can you give an example of some input and some output? Why are you converting the REMARK string to string?

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras: The example of input is `hi<script>alert('1')</script>` and output it renders is some unwanted characters. For string, its my mistake as it is already a string

Comment: Can you post the output too? Is it somethin like: `hialert('1')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how the Sanitizer works

```
string REMARK = "hi<script>alert('1')</script>";
string strRemarks = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(Convert.ToString(REMARK));
Console.WriteLine("Sanitizer output:" + strRemarks);
```

This will properly show `hi` as output. Why? Because the sanitizer will totally remove everything but the html tags.

The `script` tag is a definite problem as most xss attacks start with injecting some kind of javascript.

To make your code work change your if to

```
 if (strRemarks.Equals(REMARKS))
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Comment: The sanitizer will just remove the vulnerable part of the string and keep the rest.

Comment: Check the updated answer. I think I figured out what you want to achieve.

Comment: There is no javascript in the string above, so there is nothing to sanitize. The anchor tag is a perfectly valid and safe sting.

Comment: No, it will remain as it is. It will still be a link. The sanitizer's purpose is to create safe html (but html all the same). So nothing will be stripped of the anchor tag.

Comment: Cheers! Be glad to have in Greece!

Comment: Absolutely! What is it that you need?

Comment: its related to HOST Header Injection...The tester raised issue like.. `Server is accepting user defined Host value in HTTP request which results in Open Redirection. Further, it can also be used to perform Web-Cache Poisoning and Session Hijacking.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204478/discussion-between-hud-bhaisahab-and-athanasios-kataras).